# How to extract Subject, Object, Verb through a parser

Tags: computational-linguistics, parts-of-speech, lexical-semantics

For my project, I need to extract Subject, Object and Verb from the sentence. I have read that, LFG F structure is what I need. I am using Stanford NLP package. I couldnt find out how to do that in Stanford NLP. I have seen a post using NLTK which converts Dependency parser output to F Structure. Can anyone point to how do that using any of these packages?

Comment: See the dependency output of the Stanford parser. You can test it online at http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/. F-structure is a concept that's limited to LFG, as far as I know. In other formalisms, they use other names.